# resize image to fixed size, add border if needed

Tags: java

I need to make images I downloaded from flickr to fit into a 500x500 shape. If the aspect ratio is not 1:1 than black bars should be added to top / bottom or left / right to fill empty space. Transparent background could also work. Important is 500x500 and resizing without cropping. how can I do it in java?

Comment: We encourage you to [research your questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask). If you've [tried something already](http://whathaveyoutried.com/), please add it to the question- if not, research and attempt your question first, and then come back.

Comment: all i could find was making thumbnails, which is not what I need. no cropping, no streching of the image can occur.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Kris,

You can give [imgscalr](https://github.com/rkalla/imgscalr) a try; it implements the most optimized method for scaling images in Java and also (by default) honors the orientation and proportions of the original image when resizing... it also provides a very handy [pad(...)](http://www.thebuzzmedia.com/downloads/software/imgscalr/javadoc/org/imgscalr/Scalr.html#pad%28java.awt.image.BufferedImage,%20int,%20java.awt.Color,%20java.awt.image.BufferedImageOp...%29) operation that will give you the border you want.

The only thing it won't do for you is auto-pad the difference between the scaled picture and a perfectly square 500x500 size but you *can* scale the image to something like 498x498 -- it will give you a proportional result fitting the primary dimension (horz or port depending on orientation) and then you can pad(2) to give it a nice border with any color you want including a transparent one.

For example, the code would look something like this (using static imports for readability):

```
import org.imgscalr.Scalr.*;
import java.awt.Color;

public static BufferedImage createThumbnail(BufferedImage img) {
    // Target width of 500x500 is used
    img = resize(img, 500); 
    return pad(img, 2, Color.BLACK);
}
```

The resize() method takes [any number of additional arguments](http://www.thebuzzmedia.com/downloads/software/imgscalr/javadoc/org/imgscalr/Scalr.html#resize%28java.awt.image.BufferedImage,%20org.imgscalr.Scalr.Method,%20org.imgscalr.Scalr.Mode,%20int,%20int,%20java.awt.image.BufferedImageOp...%29) for adjusting fitting behavior, image quality, speed-of-operation, etc.

You can also apply any of the pre-defined OPs on the resulting image before returning it ([here](http://www.thebuzzmedia.com/downloads/software/imgscalr/javadoc/org/imgscalr/Scalr.html#OP_ANTIALIAS)) by passing it as the last arg to resize or pad (or any of the other operations).

Additionally if you are trying to do this in a server process and want to run these ops asynchronously, you can look at the [AsyncScalr](http://www.thebuzzmedia.com/downloads/software/imgscalr/javadoc/org/imgscalr/AsyncScalr.html) class which offers *all* the same functions, but queues the operations up against a [configurable](http://www.thebuzzmedia.com/downloads/software/imgscalr/javadoc/org/imgscalr/AsyncScalr.html#THREAD_COUNT) number of scaling threads to avoid saturating the host machine.

imgscalr has been deployed in a number of server and client scenarios in production over the last few years. I'd love to hear your feedback if you get a chance to try out the library.

Comment: thanks, that is what I needed. I used a combination of the resizing, padding and cropping methods to get all images onto a black 500x500 square with added borders on top/bottom or left/right if needed.